# How do I create a query using System.Data.Entity similar to a [SELECT * FROM "" WHERE "" ] SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

For example I have the following query already which works fine:

```
public user Get(int id)
{
    return userContext.users.Find(id);
}
```

However I would like a query which will return the object that contains the given email, so far I have this which doesn't work:

```
public user GetEmail(string email)
{
    return userContext.users.Find(email);
}
```

I'm guessing because it requires a primary key as an input.

A query which would return the user that has the given email is what I'm looking for :).

(for context) VVV

```
private LoopDatabaseEntities userContext = null;

public UserRepository()
{
    userContext = new LoopDatabaseEntities();
}
```

Comment: `using System.Linq; using System.Data.Linq; .... await userContext.Users.Where( u => u.Email == email ).ToListAsync();`

Comment: `DbSet.Find(params object[] keyValues)` method [finds an entity with the given primary key values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.find). If you want to search for the first user with matching email, use `await userContext.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email ).FirstOrDefaultAsync()`.

Comment: Or how would I return a method which would let me determine whether the email was in use or not?

Comment: You're basically asking how to filter a collection in C#. You should be able to find tons of answers on that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Find` method in Entity Framework expects the primary key as an argument and won't work for searching by email directly. You can use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`, along with LINQ to query to retrieve a user by their email.

```
public User GetByEmail(string email)
{
    return userContext.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
}
```